# Unable to add additional repos in yum. Cent OS 6.8

Tags: linux, centos6, yum

I have some problems to update some repositories.
The server os is CentOs 6.8.
To get new yum packages it was no problem to to yum update.

Until i added some additional repos.
I do not understand why this is failing.
As example, Cent OS 6.8. final

Repo is configured. As example:

```
 [mongodb]
    name=MongoDB Repository
    baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/
    gpgcheck=0
    enabled=1

Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: mongodb
```

ip tables is not running.

```
iptables: Firewall is not running.
```

This [LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217083/yum-error-while-installing-mongodb-on-centos) is not the solution, because it makes no difference which repo i add. I tried it with Fiware, MongoDB and Epel.

What do i miss. Does anyone have a helping hand ? I believe it is an network issue but don`t understand why the "normal" yum update is working.
Any ideas ?

Cheers
Ch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to assign a new IP-Adress. And a reload to the firewall rules.